# How to display mouse coordinates in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, mouseevent

I am trying to get the code below to display the coordinates in info_panel but it is not working. How would I get the coordinates from the mouseListener from SimpleFrameViewWidget to be displayed in the info_panel? I am using setText right now... Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Frame f = A7Helper.readFromURL("http://www.cs.unc.edu/~kmp/kmp.jpg");
    f.setTitle("");
    SimpleFrameViewWidget simple_widget = new SimpleFrameViewWidget(f);

    JFrame main_frame = new JFrame();
    main_frame.setTitle("Assignment 7 Pixel Inspector");
    main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel top_panel = new JPanel();
    top_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    top_panel.add(simple_widget, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    main_frame.setContentPane(top_panel);


    JPanel info_panel = new JPanel();
    info_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    top_panel.add(info_panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    JLabel x_label = new JLabel("");
    x_label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    x_label.addMouseListener(simple_widget);
    x_label.setText(simple_widget.getStringInfo());
    info_panel.add(x_label);


    main_frame.setContentPane(top_panel);
    main_frame.pack();
    main_frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is the code that has the mouseListener and mouseClick. Thanks in advance!

```
public class SimpleFrameViewWidget extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

private FrameView frame_view;
private String stringInfo;


public SimpleFrameViewWidget(Frame f) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame_view = new FrameView(f);
    frame_view.addMouseListener(this);
    add(frame_view, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLabel title_label = new JLabel(f.getTitle());
    add(title_label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();

    stringInfo = "X: " + x + "Y: " + y;
}

public String getStringInfo(){
    return stringInfo;
}
```

Comment: You haven't specified _how_ you want it displayed?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: `Frame f = A7Helper.readFromURL("http://www.cs.unc.edu/~kmp/kmp.jpg");`  That is a strangely named method for something that returns a `Frame`!

Answer (score 0):

### You Could...

Register another `MouseListener` to `SimpleFrameViewWidget` that simply feed the results directly to `info_panel` or have `info_panel` do it all for you....